# Do these Diophantine equations have solutions?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

In [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/30376/83426)/[this blog post](http://math.andrej.com/2006/11/04/are-small-sentences-of-peano-arithmetic-decidable/) by Andrej Bauer, he mentions finding these two short Diophantine equations, which "gave a professional number theorist something to munch on for a couple of weeks":

$$\exists \, a,b,c. \; a^2 - 2 = (a + b) \, b \, c$$

and

$$\exists \, a,b,c. \; a^2 + a - 1 = (a + b) \, b \, c$$

(with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$), but gives no hint about the outcome of the munching.

Do either of these equations have solutions?  I have already checked all $a,b,c \le 10^5$.

Comment: You could write to Bauer. I do know of a much earlier paper, by Julia Robinson, that used Diophantine equations to draw conclusions about, well, decidability.

Comment: In both equations, $a$ must be even and $b$ must be odd. In the first equation, $c$ must be congruent to $6$ modulo $8$ , in the second equation, $c$ must be congruent $3$ modulo $4$. Maybe this helps.